# How can non-blocking disk I/O be implemented?

Tags: unix, disk, io, nonblocking

How can non-blocking disk I/O be implemented?

I'm interested in file and raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also, checkout [AIO](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aio.html)

Answer (score -2):

- [Select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)
- [O_NONBLOCK](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)
- [Poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)

Comment: select() and poll() does not work on regular files and block devices